# com.github.bumptech.glide:glide making app crash

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to develop a messaging app in android studio using firebase.
there are no syntax error at all. 
but when I use  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0' dependencies
I already tried changing dependencies version but it does not work.
the app crashes whether I have used glide in or not.
can someone tell me what went wrong and how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

.class file

```
package kanti.kushal.team;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import kanti.kushal.team.Model.User;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView username;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        profile_image =findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        username =findViewById(R.id.username);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user =dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                if(user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                }
                else{
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,StartActivity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
2020-05-04 07:27:17.148 13377-13377/? I/nti.kushal.tea: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-05-04 07:27:17.170 13377-13377/? E/nti.kushal.tea: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2020-05-04 07:27:17.375 13377-13377/kanti.kushal.team W/nti.kushal.tea: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
2020-05-04 07:27:17.380 13377-13377/kanti.kushal.team E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:272)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:881)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:976)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1227)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2562)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2554)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:240)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2061)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:877)
                ... 13 more
2020-05-04 07:27:17.386 13377-13377/kanti.kushal.team I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-05-04 07:27:17.394 13377-13377/kanti.kushal.team D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-04 07:27:17.396 13377-13377/kanti.kushal.team E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kanti.kushal.team, PID: 13377
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6793)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:240)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2061)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7381)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6793) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:240) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2061) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/kanti.kushal.team-OTM4Wfvta-iKPUM0Clt1FA==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:877)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:976)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1227)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2562)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2554)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                ... 8 more
2020-05-04 07:27:17.413 13377-13377/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13377 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `build.gradle`

```
  android {

         compileOptions {
             sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
             targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         }
          ...
         defaultConfig {
             ...
             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}
```